# Installing Spectron

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, spectron

I try to install **Spectron**, by using this command:

```
 npm install --save-dev spectron
```

but I get this Err msg:

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "spectron"
>   npm ERR! node v6.9.2 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9 npm ERR! code ENOSELF
>
> npm ERR! Refusing to install spectron as a dependency of itself npm
>    ERR! npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\spectron-master\npm-debug.log

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you setting 'name' to in your package.json? If it's "spectron", you'll get this error. "spectron-master" should be fine, though...

Comment: can you post package.json contents in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set any name in the package.json by default the folder name is taken.

You can't install a Package which is same like the name in package.json.

example : trying to install Spectron in a project having the name Spectron in package.json is supposed to raise this error.